# How to set a new firestore get listener after the previous one is completed

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firestore database I have a data structure like this:
Units > Unit 1-15 > Words > Documents of words

I want to get the words in each unit.
I want to get the words in unit x after I have fully retrieved the words from unit x-1

I thought about making a method that gets the words from a specific unit and returns true once it's done, so in the main program I can check whether the method has returned true, I can get the words from the next unit.

I tried to use onSuccessListener/onCompleteListener but no avail

I'm getting the words in this way: (Works fine)

```
        String mainCollection = "Units";
    String document = "Unit " + unitNumber;
    String subCollection = "Words";

        CollectionReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection(mainCollection)
                .document(document).collection(subCollection);

        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                        Word currentWord = queryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(Word.class);
                        wordsDatabase.wordDao().insertAWord(currentWord); //Inserts the words to Room database table
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

*over 500 document in every Words collection so it may takes some time with weak internet connection*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd typically do this by declaring a function that invokes itself:

```
int unitNumber = 1;
String mainCollection = "Units";
String document = "Unit " + unitNumber;
String subCollection = "Words";

getWordsFor(1);

public void getWordsFor(int unitNumber) {
    CollectionReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection(mainCollection)
            .document(document).collection(subCollection);

    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    Word currentWord = queryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(Word.class);
                    wordsDatabase.wordDao().insertAWord(currentWord); //Inserts the words to Room database table
                }

                // if there are more units to read, kick off the next one
                if (unitNumber < 15) {
                    getWordsFor(unitNumber+1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So we kick it off with `getWordsFor(1)` and then after it's done reading, the function check if there's more work to do, and reinvokes itself if that's the case.